# vim : insert mode problem : remaps (imap) and abbreviations (ab) in .vimrc don't work

Tags: vim

I have a problem in vim:
If I modify the .vimrc file and add this lines:

```
map ;bb A78
```

it just works in normal mode.
If I got it, it should work in insert mode too, shouldn't it?
While editing, I've verified that everything was read properly (command ":map"):

```
i  ;bb           A78
```

If I do the same thing with "imap", I got the same problem: command ":imap" shows it's configured, but if I go in insert mode, and type ";bb" or ";bb" or ";bb" nothing is changed, I don't get the A78

What am I missing?
(And the marvellous [codeSnippet](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2540) plugin works only in normal mode too, which is a big problem to me)

If forgot to precise: I have only the plugin Tabularize, it's vim version 7.3 under cygwin, but I get the same problem in SSH / Linux Debian / vim version 7.0

If I try to do exactly what written [here](http://my.safaribooksonline.com/book/operating-systems-and-server-administration/linux/0596006403/editing-text-files-with-joe-and-vim/linuxckbk-chp-6-sect-10) (to give another try, if it may help), that doesn't work either: "To use the abbreviation, switch to Insert mode and type th, followed by any whitespace above (space, tab, or carriage return)." doesn't work *at all*. This drives me nuts.

Here follows my .vimrc file, maybe there's something wrong here I didn't see:

```
set nocompatible
filetype plugin on
syntax enable

set ignorecase
set paste
set ruler
set modeline

set showcmd

set expandtab
set tabstop=2
set autoindent
set smartindent

set number
colorscheme desert

set vb t_vb=

set backup
set backupdir=~/.vim/backup
set directory=~/.vim/tmp
set fileencodings=utf-8,ucs-bom,default,latin1
set scrolloff=5
set undolevels=1000
nmap ;bw :. w! ~/.vimxfer<CR>
nmap ;br :r ~/.vimxfer<CR>
nmap ;ba :. w! >>~/.vimxfer<CR>

" Tell vim to remember certain things when we exit
"  '10 : marks will be remembered for up to 10 previously edited files
"  "100 : will save up to 100 lines for each register
"  :20 : up to 20 lines of command-line history will be remembered
"  % : saves and restores the buffer list
"  n... : where to save the viminfo files
set viminfo='10,\"100,:20,%,n~/.viminfo

" when we reload, tell vim to restore the cursor to the saved position
augroup JumpCursorOnEdit
 au!
 autocmd BufReadPost *
 \ if expand("<afile>:p:h") !=? $TEMP |
 \ if line("'\"") > 1 && line("'\"") <= line("$") |
 \ let JumpCursorOnEdit_foo = line("'\"") |
 \ let b:doopenfold = 1 |
 \ if (foldlevel(JumpCursorOnEdit_foo) > foldlevel(JumpCursorOnEdit_foo - 1)) |
 \ let JumpCursorOnEdit_foo = JumpCursorOnEdit_foo - 1 |
 \ let b:doopenfold = 2 |
 \ endif |
 \ exe JumpCursorOnEdit_foo |
 \ endif |
 \ endif
 " Need to postpone using "zv" until after reading the modelines.
 autocmd BufWinEnter *
 \ if exists("b:doopenfold") |
 \ exe "normal zv" |
 \ if(b:doopenfold > 1) |
 \ exe "+".1 |
 \ endif |
 \ unlet b:doopenfold |
 \ endif
augroup END

set backspace=2
inoremap <silent> <Bar>   <Bar><Esc>:call <SID>align()<CR>a

function! s:align()
  let p = '^\s*|\s.*\s|\s*$'
  if exists(':Tabularize') && getline('.') =~# '^\s*|' && (getline(line('.')-1) =~# p || getline(line('.')+1) =~# p)
    let column = strlen(substitute(getline('.')[0:col('.')],'[^|]','','g'))
    let position = strlen(matchstr(getline('.')[0:col('.')],'.*|\s*\zs.*'))
    Tabularize/|/l1
    normal! 0
    call search(repeat('[^|]*|',column).'\s\{-\}'.repeat('.',position),'ce',line('.'))
  endif
endfunction

:autocmd BufNewFile  * silent! 0r ~/.vim/templates/%:e.tpl
:autocmd BufNewFile  *.php call search('w', '', line("w$"))
```

Thanks a lot!

Comment: do you type quickly enough ? If you are too slow your mapping is interpreted as 3 distinct keys. I have tried `:imap ;bb A78` here and when I type `;bb` it inserts `A78`

Comment: °_° I don't know who asked for "close for off topic", because if you read the FAQ: "What kind of questions can I ask here?" => "software tools commonly used by programmers"....

Comment: @Xavier this is not related specifically to ";bb" ... I've added this url http://my.safaribooksonline.com/book/operating-systems-and-server-administration/linux/0596006403/editing-text-files-with-joe-and-vim/linuxckbk-chp-6-sect-10 and it doesn't work at all for me (on both systems). And I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to make sure that vim is not in "paste" mode.

Try

```
:set nopaste
```

Comment: +1 'paste' is disabling abbreviations and Insert mode mapping so it is likely the solution !

Comment: When the 'paste' option is switched on (also when it was already on):
                - mapping in Insert mode and Command-line mode is disabled
                - abbreviations are disabled
                - 'textwidth' is set to 0
                - 'wrapmargin' is set to 0
                - 'autoindent' is reset
                - 'smartindent' is reset
                - 'softtabstop' is set to 0
                - 'revins' is reset
                - 'ruler' is reset
                - 'showmatch' is reset
                - 'formatoptions' is used like it is empty
ERRRRRRG

Comment: Thank you very much I though I was about to go crazy (I've been looking for this solution for more than 5 hours now)!

Comment: I had been trying to figure this out for DAYS. This is the only place I found this mentioned. I had no idea `set paste` disabled all mapping. THANK YOU!

Answer (score 2):

`map` doesn't make the mapping work in insert mode: for ALL modes, you want `map!`.  See `:help :map!` for more information on this.

However, `imap` should work, so you're probably having issues either with timeouts or the 'paste' setting.  The way a mapping works in insert mode is that it gives you a certain amount of time to enter the mapping (I think the default is 1 second) and if you type it slower than that it assumes you mean the individual characters.  So if you do:

```
:map! ;bb A78
```

And then type:

```
;<pause>bb
```

(where `<pause>` is just a pause, not something you type)

You'll get `;bb`, but if you type:

```
;bb
```

really quickly, you'll get `A78`.

To find out more about timeouts, have a look at these help pages:

```
:help 'timeout'
:help 'ttimeout'
:help 'timeoutlen'
:help 'ttimeoutlen'
```

The `'paste'` option also has an effect: it disables mappings in insert mode and abbreviations.  Try `:set paste?` to find out if you have this set and `:set nopaste` to disable it.

See:

```
:help 'paste'
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, this was very informative.